# Where to set CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I create a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` this way:

```
// Create the preview layer
_videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
[_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
_videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer atIndex:0];
```

And now I want to do this:

```
_videoPreviewLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
```

But if I put it before `[_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];` I get different results than I put it after.

**Where do I have to apply scale?**

And, if I want to set `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2); // -90 degrees`, where do I have to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use setFrame on a view whose transform is not the identity.  According to Apple's documentation on the frame property of UIView:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property [frame] is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

And in UIView.h, above the frame property

> do not use frame if view is transformed since it will not correctly reflect the actual location of the view. use bounds + center instead.

So you will probably get the consistent results you're looking for if you switch to using setBounds and setCenter instead of setFrame in this code.

To answer the question directly: There's no correct place to put either of these transforms (the scale or the rotation) if you are also using setFrame.  If you use setBounds and setCenter then you will get the same results whether you apply the transforms before setBounds/setCenter or after setBounds/setCenter.

**EDIT: VansFannel points out that this is a CALayer, not a UIView, so the above comments don't really apply.  I'm leaving them so as not to deprive VansFannel's comment of context, and also because it's still a good warning to have for UIViews**

Now, for CALayers, if you set the frame (like [_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds]) that will cause _videoPreviewLayer's actual rendered frame to be self.view.bounds even if _videoPreviewLayer has a non-identity transform.  It's important to remember that CALayer's frame is actually a derived property.  It's derived from the layer's bounds, position, anchorPoint, and transform.  When you use setFrame QuartzCore will figure out a bounds and position that yields the frame you passed to setFrame under the existing anchorPoint and transform.

So if you want those transforms to have any effect you should put them *after* your call to setFrame.  If you set the transforms first then setFrame will effectively negate them.  If you absolutely need to set the transforms first then you must avoid setFrame and work with the layer's bounds and position directly.

Comment: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is a CALayer, not a UIView. I don't if it matters.

Comment: @VansFannel You're right and it does make a difference.  I've updated my answer to explain the situation with CALayers.  The short version is:  Put setFrame first if you want your transforms to do anything.